# Mobile dropdown menu wont close javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I am trying to have a hamburger menu on my mobile website.

When viewed on a mobile device, The menu opens on a click but will not collapse on a click once the menu is open. -THIS IS MY ISSUE

This is basic HTML for my issue.

I am using magento 1.9.2.3

The php code are the "toplinks". These do not need to be working to solve this problem.

HTML

```
<div class="mobile-links">

        <div id="dropdown" onClick="myFunction()">
        <button class="dropbtn">
        <span><img src="http://www.smockedoverstocks.net/skin/frontend/lee/default/images/hamburger-menu.png"/></span></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="quick-access five columns omega">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

---

Javascript that controls the menu:

```
        <script language="javascript">
 /* When the user clicks on the button, 
 toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
 function myFunction(ev) {
document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle(show);
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
  Dropdown.classList.remove('show')};

  }
}
}
}
</script>
```

---

CSS for the menu:

```
.mobile-links .dropdown {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:2px 13px 0px;
}

.mobile-links .dropdown-content{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 5px 12px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
#dropdown.show .dropdown-content {
display:block;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are using `document.getElementById("myDropdown")` - but there is no element with the id "myDropdown". Also, you defined an "onclick" element, which ist not valid HTML - it should be a button element with an onclick attribute, so `<button onclick="...` Or will the `myDropdown` element be rendered by the PHP `getChildHtml()` function? Without you providing the actual content, we can just guess...

Comment: Also, `.classList.collapse()` is not a valid method.

Comment: wouldnt "myDropdown" be a the result of the class "dropdown" with an onclick "myFunction" so it would become "myDropdown" ?

Comment: and where in your code is that magic supposed to happen? :) Because currently, you are just selecting an element with the id "myDropdown" from the DOM - but there is no element with that id.

Comment: also, after changing your code, you now have a `class` element and you have missed the closing double quote of the `onclick` attribute on the `class="dropdown"` element.

Comment: For better understanding: do you still want to keep the hiding/showing on hover and add the click toggle as an addition?

Comment: Hey- I have updated the code more. I did not see where I was missing the double closing quotes in class="drop-down"
I am only using this hamburger menu on mobile devices, so hover would not be needed. I just need to able to click it open and click it closed on a mobile device. Once the screen gets bigger, the menu turns into a normal website menu. With the way the code is now, it opens but does not close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have at this adapted live example: Is this the behaviour you were looking to achieve?

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */

function myFunction(ev) {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle('show');
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.collapse('show');

  }
  }
  }
  }
```

```css
.mobile-links .dropdown {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:2px 13px 0px;
  }

.mobile-links .dropdown-content{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 5px 12px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,
#dropdown.show .dropdown-content {
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mobile-links">
      <div id="dropdown" onclick="myFunction()">
        <button class="dropbtn">
        <span><img src="http://www.smockedoverstocks.net/skin/frontend/lee/default/images/hamburger-menu.png"/></span></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="quick-access five columns omega">
          content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. 
Your button works perfectly on here. When I make the changes in my code, the menu opens but still will not close when clicked again on mobile. 

Could the hover have something to do with it? 
I only need the menu to open and close on a click on a mobile device

Comment: Then you can completely remove the hover and from the styles!

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
   <div class="dropdown">
      <onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
```

is incorrect format. `onClick` should be inline with your `<div>` like so,

```
 <div class="dropdown" onClick="myFunction()">
```

or on a different user interface element. Next,

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
```

should be changed to,

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle();
```

Set the initial state of `myDropdown` to `hide()` . For example,

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myDropdown').hide();
  }
```

This specifies an element to perform an action after the page has loaded. You could set it entirely with `css` by giving a `display` property of `none` and setting a trigger to change the `display` property to `block` on `click` or `hover` . Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Ive adjusted the code in the original post to reflect the things that you said to change. 

How would I set the inital state on myDropdown to hide()?

I am new to java so am trying to read up as much as I can.

Comment: @L.Blanchard Please don't confuse JavaScript with Java.

Comment: i'll make an edit with an example for setting initial state